# How to launch the Point-Of-Sale Android app from Xaramin.Forms?

Tags: android, square-connect

Is there a way to launch the Square POS Android app from Xamarin.Forms? I noticed all the SDK examples are in Java. Does the app have to be written using Java?

EDIT: Update

I created Bindings library in Visual Studio using the square android SDK aar file. Now, it launches the Point-of-Sale app but then it afterwords no result data is being sent back to the application. Instead, it goes to an error screen where it says "Webpage not available"

The webpage at
intent#intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE (more..)
could not be loaded because

net: ERROR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

I am trying to do this in a WebView by overriding ShouldOverrideUrlLoading

```
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
            {
                if (url.StartsWith("http:") || url.StartsWith("https:"))
                {
                    view.LoadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }

                if (url.Contains("CHARGE"))
                {
                    // Process Square Point-Of-Sale Transaction
                    ChargeRequest chargeRequest =
                        new ChargeRequest.Builder(1, CurrencyCode.Usd)
                        .Note("Test")
                        .RequestMetadata("WEB_CALLBACK_URI=mycallbackurl")
                        .RestrictTendersTo(ChargeRequest.TenderType.Card, ChargeRequest.TenderType.CardOnFile, ChargeRequest.TenderType.Cash)
                        .CustomerId("MyCustomerID")
                        .Build();

                    try
                    {
                        if (PosClient == null)
                        {
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity).SetMessage("Square Point-Of-Sale Client Error").Show();
                        }
                        Intent chargeIntent = PosClient.CreateChargeIntent(chargeRequest);
                        this.activity.StartActivityForResult(chargeIntent, CHARGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity).SetMessage(e.Message).Show();
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
```

EDIT: Update

I added an override for OnRecieveError

> The errorCode is
>
> Android.Webkit.ClientError.Unsupported Scheme
>
> In the Webview Object there's this
>
> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method
>   "Landroid/webkit/WebView;.getRendererPriorityWaivedWhenNotVisible()Z"
>   Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method
>   "Landroid/webkit/WebView;.getRendererRequestedPriority()I"

EDIT: Update

I have it sort of working now. In the ShouldOverrideUrlLoading method, I changed it to return true if it was processing a transaction. I also had to override OnActivityResult and parse the data coming back from the Android app. It now launches the Square POS App and Returns data back to the calling app. Now, I just have figure out how to process the transaction from there.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't understand your question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @washichi I know how to ask a standard question. This is specific to square-connect https://github.com/square/point-of-sale-android-sdk

Comment: Ah okee, please make that clear in your question. 
I'm not familiar with square pos, but since its a native app  I think you can just call it with an intent: 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Comment: @washichi Right, but the SDK has functions for building the specific square-pos requests/intents. My question is how do I use their library in Xamarin?

Comment: Almost sure that is possible, because you can do platform specific code in Xamarin.

Comment: @washichi If there's no Xamarin specific library existing it might be possible to create a bindings library and include the square-pos-sdk as a jar. I was hoping that there was already something that worked.

Comment: Did you ever get this working or find a better approach? We're in the same situation, we can't integrate with the Android in-app payments SDK because it's Java-only, and can't find an open source bindings project for Xamarin either.